# Adding different arrayStates to ArrayList without changing original arrayState

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently trying to solve a 2d slider puzzle game in java. I want to solve the puzzle using BFS, but whenever I add vertices to the tree, the parent node gets changed and all the adjacent vertices are the same. Let me show some code to explain what I mean.

Here is my GameState object, which is what is representing every node in the tree.

```
public class GameState {
public int[][] state; //state of the puzzle
public GameState parent; //parent in the game tree


public GameState(int[][] state, GameState parent) {
    //initialize this.state to state, this.parent to parent
    this.state = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            this.state[i][j] = state[i][j];
        }
    }

    this.parent = parent;
}
```

And here is my method to get all possible adjacent vertices.

```
public ArrayList<GameState> getAdjacent() {
    //Use the swap functions to generate the new vertices of the tree
    //Beware of the boundary conditions, i.e. don’t swap left when you are
    //already on the left edge

    ArrayList<GameState> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;


    //Gets my zero int index
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if(this.state[i][j] == 0){
                row = i;
                col = j;
            }
        }
    }

    //Checking if we can swap up
    if(row != 0) {
        vertices.add(swapUp(this, row, col));
    }

    //Checking if we can swap down
    if(row != 2) {
        vertices.add(swapDown(this, row, col));
    }

    //Checking if we can swap left
    if(col != 0) {
        vertices.add(swapLeft(this, row, col));
    }

    //Checking if we can swap right
    if(col != 2) {
        vertices.add(swapRight(this, row, col));
    }


    return vertices;
}
```

Lastly, for example, here is what happened when swapUp is called.

```
public GameState swapUp(GameState s, int row, int col) {

    s.parent = s;

    int temp = state[row][col]; // Mark zero as temp
    s.state[row][col] = s.state[row-1][col];
    s.state[row-1][col] = temp;


    return s;
}
```

I need every gamestate added to the arrayList to be different, but when I test the program this is what gets outputted as the vertices added to the list.

```
[1, 5, 0]
[3, 7, 4]
[6, 8, 2]
1
[1, 5, 0]
[3, 7, 4]
[6, 8, 2]
2
[1, 5, 0]
[3, 7, 4]
[6, 8, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `GameState` in your `swap` methods, something like:

```
public GameState swapUp(int row, int col) {

    GameState s = new GameState(state, this);

    // no need for swap, (row,col) is 0, (row-1,col) becomes 0
    s.state[row][col] = s.state[row-1][col];
    s.state[row-1][col] = 0;

    return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the issue! @SirRaffleBuffle